# the cookie disappear when I change page

Tags: php, cookies

(PHP) I set the cookie in my login.php page in this way:

```
setcookie('cookie_id',$id);
```

I print the cookie and I see the correct value but when I change page with:

```
header($login_url);
```

I lose the all cookie and I don't know why. Anybody can help me?

Comment: To get your cookie you need do this: 
`echo $_COOKIE["myCookieName"];` so in your case it would be `$_COOKIE['cookie_id']`

Comment: Is your $login_url from the same domain as the login page? Look at domain parameter [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: Yes...and if I print $_COOKIE['cookie_id'] in the login.php first to call header I see the corrent value but if I print $_COOKIE['cookie_id'] in the page,opened with header(), I see "null". How is it possible?

Comment: Can you show the actual code in the `login.php` page as the order of event matters in these cases

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify `/` as path in `setcookie()` function, so cookie will be available on every path of your site. To do this:

```
setcookie('cookie_id', $id, 0, '/');
```

Note that third argument is expire time which is set to 0 as default. According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) it means that:

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

Answer (score 1):

If you have human urls or subfolders (like www.domain.com/path1/path2/), then you must set cookie path to / to work for all paths, not just current one.

```
setcookie('cookie_id', $cookie_id, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/');
```

From PHP manual:

The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain . If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain . The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.