# Laravel: Cookie disappears on refresh: Instead, XSRF-TOKEN is created wrongly

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

What I've been trying is to set a token (i.e. a string) as a cookie, which needs to persist for a certain period.

```
public function tokenAuth(Request $request)
{
    try {
        //Lines which create a token from input values
    } catch (MyCustomException $e) {
        //Return with a warning message
    }
    $minutes  = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; //time()+60*60*24*30 = 30 days
    $https    = false;
    $httpOnly = true;
    return response('Hello World')->cookie("MY_JWT", $token, $minutes, '/', env('APP_URL'), $https, $httpOnly);
}
```

As long as valid credentials are provided, this `tokenAuth` is supposed to put a cookie `MY_JWT`. I can see that `MY_JWT` is generated properly from Developer Tools.

[image]

However, as the title suggests, `MY_JWT` disappears upon refreshing. According to Laravel's documentation, [cookies can be generated in this way.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#cookies)

I also tried `setcookie('cookie_id', $id, 0, '/')`, referring to [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277252/the-cookie-disappear-when-i-change-page) but I still have no luck.

A funny thing I found is that `XSRF-TOKEN` is in the cookies, although I haven't put `csrf_token` in my app.

This is what happens after I refresh the page.
[image]

*The cookie named `blah` was created several days ago for an experimentation.*

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong?

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking if it is a chrome issue, try using another browser like edge

Comment: The $minutes calculation is wrong, you're having a extremely long valid time. Your screenshot shows this to be at least until year "104171...". 30 days is 60 minutes/hour * 24 hours/day * 30 days = 43200 minutes.